# Vue js : Extract actual code from production version minimized files

Tags: node.js, vue.js

We had a vue js code for one of the functionality which we have deployed in production in Production minimized form.

Now I have lost the actual code (Vue js project) so I only left with minimized files (app.js, manifest.js, vendor.js and app.css) because of this I am not able to make any changes for that functionality.

Is there any way to extract the code from production files in vue js project and modify some of the logic.

Comment: you can't but, you could use a tool like recuva to restore your deleted files

Comment: Do you have any [source maps](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)?

Comment: Yes I have .map files with me. Is there any way to get this sorted out with .map files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right anwser for this. You can only try to "hack" some way into webpack minified files. You can do it in Chrome Dev Tools when inspecting the minified file, then click on "Pretty Print" brackets below to format your code in a regular manner, but still all your original source code variables, fnames etc. are changed.. Only if you know some specific values, for examples hard-coded strings you can orient your way around it, but its a long shot...

Comment: I have .map files with me. Is there any way to get this sorted out with .map files.